# React native android app crash on start when import firebase on release only

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I try to use Firebase database in a react-native application for android
I follow this [tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html).

I use this react-native versions:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.42.0
```

And in package.json :

```
"firebase": "^3.7.0",
```

On emulator or real device in dev mode, everything works great but when I build a release apk, it crash on app start

I do many tests and the problem is on the firebase import

In logcat, I have this, any ideas ?

```
03-08 07:52:46.990  6764  6781 E ReactNativeJS: Can't find variable: ie
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6781 E ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.firebasereactnative, PID: 6764
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Can't find variable: ie, stack:
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@374:4815
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@374:4880
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@376:21072
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@376:21085
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: n@2:557
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: i@2:348
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: t@2:210
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@367:44
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: n@2:557
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: i@2:348
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: t@2:210
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@366:135
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: n@2:557
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: i@2:348
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: t@2:210
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: <unknown>@12:135
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: n@2:557
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: i@2:278
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: t@2:210
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: global code@379:9
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime: 
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:99)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:345)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:136)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
03-08 07:52:47.000  6764  6782 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-08 07:52:47.000  1252  2157 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.firebasereactnative/.MainActivity
03-08 07:52:47.000  1252  2157 W VirtualScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): top activity or app is null
```

Comment: Usually if you get crash on release but not on debug, the problem exist in your proguard configuartion files

Comment: I'm getting this same crash on iOS, so I dont think its a proguard issue

Comment: Thanks for the advice but if I remove import, it works ?!? and I change nothing in default build.gradle
I suspect bundle minification issue

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to firebase 3.6.5 seems to have fixed it for me

Comment: I try but same behavior, you are on react-native@0.42.0 ?
In logcat I have another error ?!?

`03-09 18:45:16.424  4735  4752 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'l.hasOwnProperty("process")')`

`03-09 18:45:16.428  4735  4753 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules`
`03-09 18:45:16.428  4735  4753 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.firebasereactnative, PID: 4735`
`03-09 18:45:16.428  4735  4753 E AndroidRuntime: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'l.hasOwnProperty("process")'), stack:`

Comment: I'm on react-native 0.38.0 still - I have too many issues on iOS to upgrade. based on @dcz.switcher comment below, it appears to definitely be a bug in 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Great news ! it works !
I init a new react-native project and install the last firebase version which is now 3.7.1 !
And everything is fine

Thanks for your help